# Guys Im built Hotel Management system on Laravel, and i stack edit data and update data Help me :(

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-8

If i clik submit after edit,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvCxm.png)

404 not found pages like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glVcN.png)

my code like in roomtypecontroler edit & update like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1XvC.png)

and form edit.blade.php like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aocbf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also your title is not descriptive of the problem, so doesn't attract many people to your question (other than to expect to comment to you on how to improve it).

Answer (score 2):

Your url is wrong.

Change your url to

`action="{{ url('admin/roomtype/'.$data->id) }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in `edit.blade.php` from:

`action="{{ url('admin/roomtype'.$data->id) }}"`

to

`action="{{ url('admin/roomtype/'.$data->id) }}"`

because you were posting to admin/roomtype1 instead of admin/roomtype/1

Comment: Hi @fajriadha  If this, or any answer, has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this